# Unable to extract foot.lua to map.xml

Tags: xml, lua, openstreetmap, osrm

I'm trying to implement osrm server, I have AWS Ubuntu server instance with 4 GB RAM. I have exported Indian map data from export https://www.openstreetmap.org downloaded as map.xml, now when I am trying to extract using  `osrm-extract` command I'm getting the following error

```
ubuntu@~/osrm-backend$ osrm-extract map.xml -p profiles/foot.lua
[info] Parsed 0 location-dependent features with 0 GeoJSON polygons
[info] Using script profiles/foot.lua
[info] Input file: map.xml
[info] Profile: foot.lua
[info] Threads: 2
[info] Parsing in progress..
[info] input file generated by Overpass API 0.7.54.13 ff15392f
[info] timestamp: n/a
[info] Using profile api version 2
[info] Parse relations ...
[info] Parse ways and nodes ...
[info] Parsing finished after 0.005743 seconds
[info] Raw input contains 0 nodes, 0 ways, and 0 relations, 0 restrictions
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'osrm::util::exception'
what(): There are no edges remaining after parsing.src/extractor/extractor.cpp:623
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[info] Raw input contains 0 nodes, 0 ways, and 0 relations, 0 restrictions
...
what(): There are no edges remaining after parsing.src/extractor/extractor.cpp:623

This indicates that there were no walkable ways in your map.xml, so the routing graph is empty. I need to Check that you have at least some highway= ways in your map.xml, or some other walkable way.